# How to change the sort order of custom Sprint Board columns?

Tags: tfs, scrum

I'm attempting to configure our TFS scrum setup to include a new process in development. Per the screenshot below, I've added a custom "Peer Review" process, but I want it to appear before the "Pending Review" process.

[image]

I can't reorder the items from the screenshot below

[image]

How can I achieve choosing the output order of these work process columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you are trying to [customize the workflow (Inheritance process model)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-workflow). This is only available for VSTS by now, not able with on-premise TFS.

It's not able to change the state order, it's listed in the order you add them within the States page

> **What you can't customize**
>
> You can't change the order of states (**states are listed in the order
>   you add them within the States page**, and they're listed
>   alphabetically within the drop down list of a work item form)
>
> *[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-workflow#what-you-can-customize)*

Since you could not reorder the state, to achieve your requirement. You could only use this workaround:

1. Delete "Pending Review";
2. Re-add Pending Review and then Pending Review should in sequence under Peer Review.
3. The board will also update in the same sequence.

[image]